# How to fix Russian letters in a Wine application when adjusting LANG does not help?

Tags: character-encoding, wine, locale

An application with a Russian UI shows question marks instead the most of its text (some elements are rendered ok though).

The system locale is English (en_US, en_IE), I've tried Ubuntu ant XUbuntu 12.04 with Wine 1.5.

I've tried launching the application with

```
LANG=ru_RU.utf8 wine myapp.exe
```

but it doesn't help.

I have also checked that `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` is installed.

If I use Windows, setting Russian codepage for non-unicode apps in the Control Panel solves the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for `LANG=ru_RU.utf8 wine myapp.exe`, that solved same problem for me

Answer (score 12):

Firstly, `LANG` might not suffice. Use `LC_CTYPE`. Then, if your system locale is not Russian, it's likely that you haven't installed this locale. To install it, do the following  as root (these examples are for Ubuntu, adapt them to your distro):

```
echo ru_RU.UTF-8 UTF-8 >> /var/lib/locales/supported.d/local
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

After this running e.g. `LANG=ru_RU.utf8 cal` should give you Russian calendar for current month. If this doesn't, try

```
locale-gen --purge --no-archive
```

Now you should be able to run your wine app as

```
LC_CTYPE=ru_RU.utf8 wine myapp.exe
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to do this on FreeBSD and Wine 1.5.24 by setting `LC_ALL` and `LANG` to `ru_RU.UTF-8`. Note that it is `ru_RU.UTF-8` and not `ru_RU.utf8`, with the later being an invalid locale name on my system, at least. I guess that this can be the problem on other *NIX systems, and in your specific case, too.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Unix locale has no meaning for programs running in WINE.
You should configure winodws-in-wine for Russian.

Comment: This answer used to help in the past: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2707/2119 - that's why I've tried LANG this time. If you think this is not the way, then what would you recommend?

Comment: First, `export LANG=ru_RU.utf8 appname` is wrong expression, you should omit `export` and use `LANG=ru_RU.utf appname`. Second, run Windows Control Panel in WINE and set Cyrillic.

Comment: how do you mean to run Windows Control Panel in WINE? If you mean "wine control.exe" - it results in this: http://imgur.com/31BfO - no codepage settings applet there. If you mean "wine control.exe intl.cpl" - it just does nothing (I've tried Wine's control.exe and original Windows control.exe with Wine's default and original Windows intl.cpl).